# How do I redirect the user to the last active page when they login due to session time out using php?

Tags: php, html, authentication, redirect

I have built a little software using **Vanilla PHP**, I have implemented automatic logout for logged in users who have been inactive for quite some time, thing is, I want to redirect them to the last active page before they were logged out when they login but I do not know how to start, I was going to try the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but I read where someone said that it was not a good option due to security reasons hence now I'm stuck on how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the only way to do is pass query param to url, so you can redirect to same url again. eg.`yoursite.com?redirectto="oldurl"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to store the page URL anywhere permanently, but in the query string of the redirect, or a cookie - you already know where the logout happened, just add the current URL to redirection request (I assume it points to something like /login) and viola - you have your redirection.

1. User gets logged out on `/foo/bar`
2. `/foo/bar` redirects to `/login` with the `/foo/bar` in mind (in query string, cookie, whatever you desire)
3. User logs in on `/login`
4. `/login` redirects to `goto`

❗ Please pay particular attention to sanitizing the `goto` variable if you redirect via back-end code. You don't want to let someone redirect others to `malicious.site` through your server. Perhabs you could just limit the scope of that redirect manually, by treating goto as a local route regardless of it poinitng somewhere else (if goto points to `http://example.com`, you could just redirect to `https://your.server/http://example.com` and show the 404).

Always sanitize user-controlled data before use, especially when it comes to redirects.

Example:
`https://your.site/foo/bar` (logout happened) -> `https://your.site/login?goto=/foo/bar` (user authenticates again) -> `https://your.site/foo/bar` (user keeps using the site)

Comment: This only will work, when the redirect page is still open.  I was not sure about this. 
I also thought he wants to return the user to the page the next day.

Comment: The user getting logged out server-side (f.e. right now) and the user actually visiting the site that determines whether is he logged in or not (a day, a month, a year from now) are 2 different instances, I don't see the reason why he wouldn't be able to put a script redirecting with the information about the site where the log in check failed before actual redirect.
I was logged out, I don't know about it so I visit the protected asset under /foo/bar, that site determines I need to be reauthenticated SO it puts the redirection from itself to /login. Time has no meaning in this process.

Comment: No, I do not intend to return the user to the page the next day, I only want the user to be able to return back to the last page they were working on just before they were signed out after they login again.

Answer (score 0):

> I have implemented automatic logout for logged in users who have been inactive for quite some time, thing is, I want to redirect them to the last active page before they were logged out

In order to achieve this, it would be necessary to save the last visited URI in the database e.g. in the users record.
Create e.g. a field "last_visited_page" in your user table and update it on every page visit.

On the next login just redirect to that page - if the entry is empty then redirect to standard page like your Home..

But I would not do that because this is not a behaviour the user would expect after returning to the page the next day
I have never seen this behavour on any webpage as far as i can remember.

**$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']** is wrong in any case because it is the page the user CAME from  e.g.   https://www.cdc.gov/cpr/zombie/index.htm   and **YOU DEFINITELY DO NOT WANT to redirect there :-BB

just use and save e.g.
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Or completely rethink it and do something more useful for the page visitor :-B

Comment: this is a wonderful idea, thank you, but the reason why I want to do this is because I have come across some websites where if you're logged out due to a session time out you can  log back in and get redirected to the last page you were on just before the logout. If you still think it's not a good practice then I'd be glad to leave it.

Comment: If it is a e-BANKING software or something very critical the timeout SHOULD be lower than the standard  but normally the php session is fine with standard webpages. 
And the session WILL ONLY timeout when the user has left it intentionally.